# Acceptability of using Present Perfect

Tags: present-perfect, subordinate-clauses

Good afternoon.
I once writing an exercise I found an interesting example.

1. I will send you the paper after I finish it.
2. I will send you the paper after I have finished it.

I have learnt that we usually use Present Simple in subordinate clauses as in the first statement. But than I found another example. So is there any difference in meaning between these two sentences or both of them are interchangeble? Please, explain it to me.

Comment: Both are idiomatic and in everyday use. For all practical purposes they mean the same thing.

Comment: @WS2 is correct; however, one could argue that replacing "after" with "once" would sound more natural.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I understood both are correct. The main thing we should remember is to use right and appropriate time in each of its parts (according to clauses rules).